# Access vba - code for opening and closing a Internet Explorer Window - running in different procedures

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, navigation, ms-access-2010

I've been asked to create a access database which will read in one record at a time, and display a associated website. Then after the user has changed some data, and moved to the next record, I want to ensure that the website has closed before opening the new one to ensure that the user can't mistakenly look at the wrong site.

So far I declared a public variable to manipulate the browser window (both first as an object and then specifically as a Internet Explorer object), used the visible, navigate and busy command to safely open the website via a public sub, this sub is called both at form load and form current, and then finally to try to close the window, in form current, use the quit command. See below.

```
    Public IEtest As InternetExplorer

    Public Sub OpenIE(strURL As String)

    Set IEtest = New InternetExplorer

    IEtest.Visible = True
    IEtest.Navigate strURL

    While IEtest.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Current()
    With IEtest
            .Visible = False
            .Quit
    End With

    Call OpenIE(Me.Imagelink)
    end sub
```

My problem is that the quit command is doing: nothing on the first pass when loading the form; and then when moving to a new record, I'm getting the automation error 2147417848 -...disconnected from clients...

What am I doing wrong? Can you give me code to do this best?

Answer (score 0):

this is now working and the solution is:

```
      Public IEtest As InternetExplorer

      Public Sub OpenIE(strURL As String)

       Set IEtest = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

      With IEtest
          .Visible = True
          .Navigate strURL
          .AddressBar = True
          .MenuBar = True
          .StatusBar = True
          .Toolbar = True
          .Height = 860
          .Width = 1430
          .Left = 1
          .Top = 1

          While .Busy
              DoEvents
          Wend
      End With

  End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    On Error Resume Next
    IEtest.Quit

    If Not IsNull(Me.Imagelink) Then
        Call OpenIE(Me.Imagelink)
    End If
End Sub
```